# Corda - postgres database driver (postgresql-42.2.8.jar) missing

Tags: java, postgresql, corda, postgresql-9.6

I am using **corda 4.5** with **gradle plugin version as 5.0.10** and **postgres** as my DB.
when I am trying to run deployNodes task, getting below error:

```
[ERROR] 15:51:47+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not find the database driver class. Please add it to the drivers directory. [Error Code: database-missing-driver For further information, please go to https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/error-codes.html] - Could not find the database driver class. Please add it to the 'drivers' folder. [errorCode=1oswgkz, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/1oswgkz]
```

*Following is the deployNode task code in build.gradle file:*

```
    task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp "$confidential_id_release_group:ci-workflows:$confidential_id_release_version"
        cordapp "$accounts_release_group:accounts-contracts:$accounts_release_version"
        cordapp "$accounts_release_group:accounts-workflows:$accounts_release_version"

        cordapp project(':cordapp-contracts-states')
        cordapp project(':workflows')

        //ext.drivers = ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
    }

    //NOTARY NODE

    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating: true]
        p2pAddress("localhost:10002")
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
    }

    // NODEA

    node {
        name "O=NODEA,L=Lucknow,C=IN"

        p2pAddress("localhost:10010")
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10011")
            adminAddress("localhost:10052")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[user: "userA", "password": "user123", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        //new DB config
        //DB
        extraConfig = [
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url' : 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/egdb?currentSchema=nodeA_schema',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName' : 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user' : 'postgres',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password' : 'postgres',
                //'dataSourceProperties.driverClassName' : 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource'
                //jarDirs = ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
                //'drivers' : 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                'jarDirs' : ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/jdbc/driver/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
        ]
        //jarDirs = ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
        //drivers = ext.drivers

    }

// NODEB
 node {
        name "O=NODEB,L=Delhi,C=IN"

        p2pAddress("localhost:10010")
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10011")
            adminAddress("localhost:10052")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[user: "userB", "password": "user123", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        //new DB config
        //DB
        extraConfig = [
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url' : 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/egdb?currentSchema=nodeB_schema',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName' : 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user' : 'postgres',
                'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password' : 'postgres',
                //'dataSourceProperties.driverClassName' : 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource'
                //jarDirs = ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
                //'drivers' : 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                'jarDirs' : ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/jdbc/driver/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
        ]
        //jarDirs = ['${rootProject.projectDir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.8.jar']
        //drivers = ext.drivers

    }
}
```

How to add the postgresql jdbc driver path in build.gradle file? What is the compatible postgresql verion with corda 4.5?

Answer (score 5):

It resolved the issue for me by adding the following line in `build.gradle` file in the **dependencies** section:

```
cordaDriver "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8"
```

Comment: This also worked for me on corda 4.6, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/corda/cordapp-database-setup-development-perspective-1c572adf5957):

1. PostgreSQL 9.6 is the lowest acceptable version, the article uses PostgresSQL 11.
2. The driver version is postgresql-42.1.4.jar.
3. In order to point your Gradle task to the driver; create a folder (call it `drivers`), put the driver's jar file inside of it, then inside `extraConfig` of your node, add `drivers = ['absolute_path_to_directory_with_jdbc_driver']` (notice that it's the absolute path to the **directory** that you created, not the driver **file** like you did).
4. Your node configuration is missing `database.transactionIsolationLevel`, `database.schema`, and `database.runMigration`.
5. Remove `jarDirs` and add `drivers` like I mentioned earlier.